# Initializing unknown type in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, initialization

To keep my program running smoothly, I have to create objects only when I need them. In my case, I want to see if an object of an unspecified class is null, and if not, then call tell it to initialize. (I think "initialize" is the correct term, correct me if I am wrong)

```
if (someObject == null) {
    someObject = new someObject.class()
}
```

Obviously, this code does not work. The idea seems right, but Actionscript does not agree with me. How can this be achieved?

Edit - Perhaps this will help to simplify (or complicate) the answer. I know that `someObject` extends my class `SuperClass`. Can I use a property from `SuperClass` to instantiate `someObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make an attempt at getting on the right track toward a useful answer.

Firstly, looking at your example:

```
if (someObject == null) {
    someObject = new someObject.class()
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to convey here. If `someObject` is `null`, you cannot extract any information about anything from it. Even if you type `someObject` e.g:

```
var someObject:Sprite;
```

You cannot access information about the fact that the property `someObject` is expecting a `Sprite`*

<sup>*You can use `describeType()` to access the type if `someObject` is a member of a class, but lets not go there.</sup>

If you want to be able to:

1. Check if an instance of a specific class exists, and if not;
2. Create an instance of the specified class.

You can write something like:

```
var existing:Object = { };

function findOrMake(type:Class):*
{
    var key:String = type.toString();

    if(!existing.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        // We need to make a new instance of this class.
        existing[key] = new type();
    }

    return existing[key];
}
```

Which can be used like:

```
var someObject:Sprite = findOrMake(Sprite); // Makes a new Sprite.
someObject = findOrMake(Sprite);            // References the above Sprite.
```

Comment: Though this makes my head spin, I think it's what I am looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @theseal53 I'm glad it helped, although I am curious about why you would want to do this. It sounds like you are trying to implement the singleton pattern but in an odd way.

Comment: Just looked up the singleton pattern... no, thats not where I'm going. I have rooms that need to retain  their properties after they have been entered, but before that happens, I figure that instantiating all these rooms and holding them in the memory isn't  necessary. I don't know how significantly this would  increase performance (if at all), but I think its still a valid question

Answer (score 2):

If you know what type someObject is supposed to be, it's easy:

```
var someObject:SomeClass;

if(someObject==null)
{
     someObject = new SomeClass(); // creates an instance of the class
}
```

If you don't, you're making it hard for yourself. You'll have to rethink your design I guess.

Comment: Let's suppose, theoretically, that changing my design will also drench my head with gasoline and throw a match in my hair. Is there no way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't name the instance with the exact name of the class you're instantiating.

If you do this:

```
var someobject;

if (someobject == null) 
{
    someobject = new someObject()
}
```

it works.

Comment: Uh.... perhaps I was not clear. `someObject` is the variable reference. We don't know the class of `someObject`, and it doesn't really matter what the name of the class is, just as long as we make a new one.